# Merge one column from two 2d arrays and remove duplicates

Tags: php, arrays, loops, flatten

I am running two queries, they return arrays similar to what is shown below:

First:

```
array(
    array(
        'id' => 1
    ),
    array(
        'id' => 2
    ),
    array(
        'id' => 3
    ),
    array(
        'id' => 4
    ),
)
```

Second:

```
array(
    array(
        'id' => 4
    ),
    array(
        'id' => 5
    ),
    array(
        'id' => 6
    ),
    array(
        'id' => 7
    ),
)
```

But I want to end up with

```
$ids = array(1,2,3,4,5,6,7);
```

But the only way I can think of to do that is

```
$ids = array();
foreach(array($array1, $array2) as $a){
    foreach($a as $id){
        $ids[] = $id['id'];
    }
}
$ids = array_unique($ids);
```

But that doesn't seem very efficient to me, and with the wealth of array functions out there, I am wondering if there is a better way?

Comment: Have you tried [`array_merge`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php)?

Comment: array_merge & http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1319903/how-to-flatten-a-multidimensional-array

Comment: are you sure you cant do this with a single querry

Comment: @Dagon here are the two queries: `SELECT game_id FROM user_game WHERE user_id = :userid` and `SELECT id FROM games WHERE referee_id = :userid OR reviewer_id = :userid` (syntax may be off as I use a query builder, not raw sql. but you get the idea) So, could I?

Comment: yes you could join games on user_id=referee_id

Comment: @Dagon I think in this context it is just a UNION of the two.

Comment: insufficient data to be sure ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There would be a few ways to handle this. I think I would probably start with `array_merge()` on the two original arrays, then flatten it with `array_map()`, and finally call `array_unique()`.

```
// Combine them
$new = array_merge($array1, $array2);
// Flatten them
// array_map() is used to select the 'id' key from each
$new = array_map(function($a) { 
  return $a['id'];
}, $new);
// And get the unique values
$ids = array_unique($new);

print_r($ids);
Array
(
    [0] => 1
    [1] => 2
    [2] => 3
    [3] => 4
    [5] => 5
    [6] => 6
    [7] => 7
)
```

#### Better: Do it in one query.

After seeing the query, these do not need to be two arrays. It can be done with a single `UNION` query. Using a plain `UNION` instead of a `UNION ALL` will deduplicate them for you.

```
SELECT
  game_id AS id
FROM user_game 
WHERE user_id = :userid
UNION
SELECT
  id
FROM games
WHERE referee_id = :userid OR reviewer_id = :userid
ORDER BY id
```

When fetching rows, since you have only one column, you may consider directly flattening it in the fetch.

```
// For example
while ($row = $stmt->fetch()) {
  // Pluck only the id from the row fetched
  $ids[] = $row['id'];
}
// $ids is now a 1D array.
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is what you are looking for but try:

```
array_unique(array_merge($firstArr, $secndArr));
```

Probably not as your arrays are associative but at least you can skip some of your steps.

Comment: This doesn't flatten the data.